# List files present in a directory android

Tags: android

I'm trying to display the list of all the files present in a directory in the smartphone.
This is the code i'm dealing with:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DIRECTORY_MOVIES/TEAM_15"); 
        Log.d("Files", "Path: " +Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DIRECTORY_MOVIES/TEAM_15");
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        }


         }
     });
}
```

So when i press the button I should see in the logcat all the files present in to the folder: /DIRECTORY_MOVIES/TEAM_15 but this is what appears:

```
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at com.example.list.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
05-02 18:02:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2616):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 18:07:08.812: I/Process(2616): Sending signal. PID: 2616 SIG: 9
```

What is wrong??

Comment: what is line number 32 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: Your code seems to be ok...Have you set the permission in manifest `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Does your button1 is really called button1 in activity_main layout?
btw, try removing the `final´ statement

Comment: -Line 32 is a closed parenthesis } but it is ok
-No I haven't set any permission in the manifest

Comment: The button name is button1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns NULL. And you try to access .toString() of a NULL variable.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason this happens is that the directory does not exist, f.listFiles() returns null